# Documentation for Twig 3.x format_currency filter options?

Tags: php, twig, icu, twig-filter

I'm trying to output localized currency in a twig 3.x template. I have installed the "Intl" extension. Setting the currency and number of fractional digits is straightforward but the output doesn't include a thousands separator. I can't find a shred of documentation anywhere for any of the options some of which have incomprehensible names like "grouping_used". Is there somewhere I can look, or have I made a mistake in the html?

Twig:

```
{{ reservation.balance_due|format_currency('USD',{fraction_digit: 0}) }}
```

Output:
$ 1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The twig extension directly maps those attributes [to intl NumberFormatter attributes](https://github.com/twigphp/intl-extra/blob/ca63f8efda3e9e46ad4ede3e3c00ec42218bfde1/IntlExtension.php#L51).
However, the NumberFormatter attributes are also [pretty scarcely documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#intl.numberformatter-constants.unumberformatattribute).

"grouping_used" maps to `NumberFormatter::GROUPING_USED`. `NumberFormatter::GROUPING_USED` is in turn mapped to the `UNUM_GROUPING_USED` constant, which is from the ICU library.
The documentation for the ICU library attributes [can be found here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/unum_8h.html#a22c3085f2e722f578a92c15a3346097f).

Unfortunately, it seems like the PHP documentation was largely copied from the ICU documentation.

As to your concrete issue, it seems like the `grouping_used` attribute is indeed what you are looking for:

```
{{ '1234'|format_currency('USD', {fraction_digit: 0, 'grouping_used': 1})}}
{# Prints: $ 1,234 #}
```

Note that `format_currency` is also affected by the current locale.

```
{{ '1234'|format_currency('USD', {fraction_digit: 0}, locale='en_US') }}
{# Also prints: $ 1,234 #}
```